# what is the purpose of string range validator

Tags: html, string, validation

I am searching over the internet but was unable to find the exact purpose and utilization of string range validator ? Can you please help me in knowing the usage .

Comment: tio validate the length of strings, like in twitter you have to tweet within 140 character

Comment: That cant we use .length property and wouldnt that be effective than a validator?

Answer (score 0):

> The RangeValidator control allows you to check whether a user's entry
>   is between a specified upper and a specified lower boundary. You can
>   check ranges within pairs of numbers, alphabetic characters, and
>   dates. Boundaries are expressed as constants.

**MSDN**

FOR STRING IS SIMPLE THE LENGTH.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_validators.htm

Comment: I have got a wide understanding and usage of other validators type . But unable to figure out the exact purpose of this type, except in dictionary use, can I assume this could be the only use of this type= String